# How i can take first array from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array containing two arrays. When I write `var_dump($array)`:

```
array(7) {
  ["Article"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "39-746У"
  }
  ["Visible"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
array(7) {
  ["Article"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "12-003"
  }
  ["Visible"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

When I write `var_dump($array[0])` i get `NULL`.
I want to change Visible in the second array, but it change in two arrays

Real code:

```
$sql2="select tblCurrencies.name as name,Price,tblArticleInfo.Name as Name,ArticleID,CategoryID,Article,Visible from tblArticles,tblArticleInfo,tblCurrencies where tblArticleInfo.ArticleID=tblArticles.Id and tblArticles.Id='{$tovar_id}' and tblArticles.currencyID=tblCurrencies.id";
$Array2=query_result_as_rows($sql2,$conn);
```

Comment: You have two different types of PHP array here, an associative array, with key-value pairs, and a non-associative array. Please read the [documentation on PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for information on how to access each.

Comment: You should also post the code that you've used to attempt to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different kinds of array here, an associative array, with key-value pairs, and a non-associative array, indexed by number.

Associative array:

```
$a_array = array(
    "Article" => "foo",
    "Visible" => " bar",
);
```

Access data in an associative array:

```
echo $a_array['Article'];
// prints 'foo'
```

Iterate through an associative array:

```
foreach ($a_array as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key, $value; ";
}
// prints 'Article, foo; Visible, bar'
//
```

A numerically-indexed array:

```
$num_array = ('pip', 'pap', 'pop');
```

Access items in a numerically-indexed array:

```
echo $num_array[0] . ", " . $num_array[2];
// prints 'pip, pop'
```

Iterate through the array:

```
foreach ($num_array as $num) {
    echo "$num! ";
}
// prints "pip! pap! pop! "
```

You have an associative array with a numerically-indexed array inside it:

```
$array = array(
    'Article' => array( '39-746У' ),
    'Visible' => array( '1' )
);
```

`var_dump` of `$array`:

```
array(2) {
  ["Article"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "39-746У"
  }
  ["Visible"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

To access data, you need to combine the two methods:

```
echo $array['Article'][0];
// prints "39-746У"
```

To iterate through the arrays:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) { // this is the outer associative array
    echo "outer array key: $key...\n";  // $value is the inner array
    foreach ($value as $v) { // $value is a numerically-indexed array
        echo "inner array item: $v\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
outer array key: Article
inner array item: 39-746У
outer array key: Visible
inner array item: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround:

```
$array = array(...);
$array_keys = array_keys($array);
$array_first_key = $array_keys[0];
var_dump($array[$array_first_key]);
```

also:

```
var_dump(array_shift($array));
```

With php 5.4+

```
array_values($array)[0];
```

Comment: I still get the values ​​from the two arrays

Comment: sorry, I meant the array itself. Not how you get it.